# How can be sure about that is slave machine's response data return correctly in JMeter distributing testing?

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed, remote-server

I want to make a distributing testing.When I tested target sites in my master computer;return response data correctly,but when I tested target sites from remotely(slave machine),response data is empty and starting the test on host "slavemachine's ip",finished the test on host "slavemachine's ip"appears slave machine's jmeter-server.I did the steps in this link carefully.
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

How can be sure about that is slave machine's response data return correctly in JMeter distributing testing? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `mode=Standard` line to *user.properties* file of all slave machines or pass the same argument via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jmode=Standard -s -j jmeter-server.log ....
```

References:

- [Using a different sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)